# navigation that pans to markers on a saved google map

Tags: google-maps

I've been looking through the google api and I've been having trouble finding info on how you would make marker navigation.  For example http://maps.google.com/maps/ms?msid=214364913744716823698.00046c8f8a60625db2c21&msa=0&ll=48.068903,-91.109619&spn=0.537763,0.883026

I've made this map with three markers, I'd like to embed this into mysite and then have three links that match up with the markers, and when you click the link it pans the map to that maker.  Is it possible to do this using a saved google map?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a complete example.  Basically, the map.setCenter command will allow you to move from one point to another

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html> 
<head> 
  <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/> 
  <title>Demo</title> 
  <script src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false" 
          type="text/javascript"></script>
</head> 
<body>
  <div> 
     <a href="#" onclick="map.setCenter(a);">Point A</a> 
     <a href="#" onclick="map.setCenter(b);">Point B</a>
     <a href="#" onclick="map.setCenter(c);">Point C</a>
  </div>
  <div id="map" style="width: 640px; height: 480px;"></div>

  <script type="text/javascript">
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
      zoom: 9,
      center: new google.maps.LatLng(40.00, -104.00),
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.TERRAIN
    });

    var a = new google.maps.LatLng(40.00, -104.00);
    var b = new google.maps.LatLng(41.00, -105.00);
    var c = new google.maps.LatLng(39.00, -103.00);

    new google.maps.Marker({
        position: a,
        map: map
    });

    new google.maps.Marker({
        position: b,
        map: map
    });

    new google.maps.Marker({
        position: c,
        map: map
    });  
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: so this is great, one question though,  if I have a map saved in My Places on google, there are points saved on that with little blurbs, can these be accessed, or does putting in the corresponding coordinates like in this example simply pull those up?

Comment: You would have to go through some additional steps to show your My Places map on your own website (which is what you say you want to do in the original question).  Those steps would involve exporting your map to KML, hosting that KML file on a server somewhere, and than loading that KML file as a map layer when someone visits your site.  It may be easier for you to use a custom infowindow to display the text that you want.  More info here: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/overlays#InfoWindows

Comment: okay, so you can't get access right to the saved map, that's to bad.  BUT good to know, thanks for that link, I'll do the custom interface, thanks for getting back to me on that, I really appreciate it!

Comment: can I ask one more question, I'm using it at as info page for a trip, everything works like it should in a computer web browser, but when I look at it with an iPhone for example the rest of the page is just blank white, do you have any idea why that's happening?

Comment: I don't have an iPhone,  but I tried on my Android phone, and the map displays ok.  I will say that the page you have is not optimized for mobile devices.  You have lots of fixed widths that do not translate well.  It may make more sense to come up with a mobile version of the page rather than trying to figure out what the issue is with the display.

Comment: got it, okay, thanks for taking the time to help me out, I really appreciate it.

Comment: Glad to have been able to help.